# Dragon not appearing at Bonestrewn Crest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've heard that this particular dragon has been causing problems for people in that it won't die and whatnot, but it won't even spawn for me :(. I have a bounty for this dragon, so I would like to take care of it as soon as possible, but there's absolutely no sign of it anywhere. I've learned the word, looted the chest, and even ran around and fast travelled, but it's not appearing.

Am I missing something? :(.

Thanks!

xx

Comment: I've run into this problem a few times. Once, I went there and it took off and started flying backwards... So, I'll be interested in this answer...

Comment: What version of the game are you running?

Comment: It's a bug/glitch (probably) caused by the 1.2 patch. Try loading an earlier game save. http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bonestrewn_Crest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is 1 of a Plethora of known in game bugs sadly...
pre patch you wouldn't have run into this but on rare occasions.
patch 1.2 upped this rare percentage by the dragon flying backwards anomaly.
patch 1.3 outcome on this particular bug has yet to be realized as of yet.
sadly reverting to an earlier Save doesn't Undo your choice to PATCH
to whatever version you have since patches Alter your game saves file
and clearing the cache does not fix this :(

so in summary your Pooched like the rest of us encountering this and others bugs post patches and DLC unless you have access to Console Commands...

hope this helped

Comment: if say you had patched up to 1.3 played and saved,then decided to clear your cache so you could try and play with no patches for Skyrim,you wouldn't be able to play your old 1.3 patched saves

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you killed the dragon before discovering the actual location and before you got the bounty.

That's what I did then I got the bounty, received the undiscovered location, discovered it, got the word, looted the chest; but since I already killed the dragon like 100 game time hours ago it won't complete the quest... Now I can't get the wind helm house... After I did all that work for saving the whole city from a serial killer too!